# Basic Typescript Types

Tags: code-golf

Typescript is a typed superset of Javascript. For this challenge, we'll consider the following classic [basic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html):

- `string`
- `number`
- `boolean`
- `undefined`
- `null`

And two "meta" types:

- `any`
- `never`

The type `any` annotates that any type is valid:

```
const a: any = "foo";
const b: any = 42;
const c: any = true;
const d: any = undefined;
```

Whereas `never` annotates that no type is valid:

```
const e: never = <no valid literal assignment possible>;
```

We'll also consider two compositions of types: [unions and intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html), annotated as `|` and `&` respectively.

A union type expects either one or the other type:

```
const f: string | number = "foo";
const g: string | number = 42;
```

While an intersection creates a combination of both types:

```
const h: string & any = "foo";
const i: string & any = 42;
const j: string & number = <no valid literal assignment possible>;
```

The order of operands within unions and intersections doesn't matter, `string | number` is equal to `number | string`.

### The challenge

Given one of the above type declarations, return the resulting resolved type. The input will be one of the following:

- a basic type as listed above or;
- a meta type as listed above or;
- a union of two basic and/or meta types or;
- an intersection of two basic and/or meta types.

### Examples

```
// All basic and meta types simply map to themselves
string → string
number → number
any → any
never → never

// Unions between basic types create unions except with themselves
string | number → string | number
string | undefined → string | undefined
string | string → string

// Intersections between basic types create never except with themselves
string & number → never
string & undefined → never
string & string → string

// Unions with any create any
any | string → any
any | never → any

// Intersections with any result in any except with never
any & string → any
any & number → any
any & never → never

// Unions with never yield the other half
never | string → string
never | any → any
never | never → never

// Intersections with never return never
never & string → never
never & any → never
never & never → never
```

A good way to get a feel for the types is to try out [the Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEg9gNwgJwLLQLxQM7GQSwDsBzKAMikIiWQG4g).

Any reasonable and consistent input-output format, standard loop holes, [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Comment: Why does `any & something` not give `something`? I would imagine a `number` is not both `any` and `string`

Comment: Wait, the playground does have `any & string -> any`. that feels... wrong. but i don't know ts

Comment: @hyper-neutrino It's easier explained with object types, but I omitted them to avoid making the challenge needlessly complex. A simple example is `const x: { foo: string } & { bar: number } = { foo: "foo", bar: 42 };`.

Comment: oh, okay. that makes a bit more sense but still quite strange and definitely inconvenient for golfing

Comment: We don't have to deal with object types, do we?

Comment: @user No, all the types you have to deal with are outlined in the challenge section.

Comment: FYI, this challenge encodes a fundamental misunderstanding of TypeScript. `any` is *not* the type that annotates that any type is valid; [`unknown` is](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type). Rather, `any` is a non-type that’s used for interoperability with untyped JavaScript, behaving contradictorily as both a subtype and supertype of every type. This is why `any & string` is `any`, while `unknown & string` is `string` as you’d expect. `any` should not be used in typed code, while `unknown` is safe.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>113 110 106</s>  99 bytes

```javascript
f=b=>(N='never',[x,o,y]=b.split` `,X=x<f?2:x!=N,Y=y<f?2:y!=N,!y|x==y?x:X*Y>1?'any':o>f?X?Y?b:x:y:N)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVExTsMwFN1zik@H2kYhKowBN1MZu2RpVZBIE6e4Su1gp1Uiyg2QWBjhHpyHC3CEkjRBtVvhIYrfe37vfXsZbSIdK54XF0ImbLdL6ZwO8ZgiwTZMIXdWutKt7unc03nGiwd4cCe0vEmDK788o2N3Sqv9pmo2Z9W2pLQKSn9yPh1eBigSFfLlMA0mwTSY@6Vf@WOyU@xpzRXDKNWIeIpFyS3PWFiJGA@IV8iwUFwsMGkjce9O9IiXSjWK4kesgQ7h2QEIgYL2dMZjhgcuXDVHFV9hcl2TrMxZXLDE0NSChoml0DJjXiYXeBa6oFjtCCkOSfdPD4cDQD9fb98f7/UXgQ/o@/MV3XurKG9raLNsHiUjkTQxxFtKLjBChDgvZKf3CrBWizlivZozZVMt5tRXB8erxpz9uxzhe8zpcrZguB5hB81aJCzloh4STrGDzOjeVe6Qvpli5fdN7yPm1K4Z04rpxmxxe9g/vP@P3upk45ZPW6rF7Oy/Z@ko8w0Od2/XMs3sYjZjetnMidsv)

#### How?

Although this function is not recursive, it is named explicitly and uses the argument `b` so that we can test if a string is *any* (which is the first of all types in lexicographical order) by comparing it with \$f\$. The same trick is used to distinguish between `&` and `|`.

```javascript
f = b => ...
```

We load the first type in \$x\$, the operator in \$o\$ and the second type in \$y\$. Both \$o\$ and \$y\$ may be undefined if only one type is passed in the input string.

```javascript
[x, o, y] = s.split` `
```

The pair of strings \$(x,y)\$ is turned into a pair of integers \$(X,Y)\$ by applying the following rules:

- if the type is *any*, map it to \$2\$
- if the type is *never*, map it to \$0\$
- if the type is anything else, map it to \$1\$

```javascript
N = 'never'
X = x < f ? 2 : x != N
Y = y < f ? 2 : y != N
```

We then apply the following logic:

```javascript
!y | x == y ? // if y is undefined or x = y:
  x           //   return x
:             // else:
  X * Y > 1 ? //   if X * Y > 1, which means that one of the types
              //   is 'any' and the other one is *not* 'never':
    'any'     //     return 'any'
  :           //   else:
    o > f ?   //     if this is a union, i.e. o = '|':
      X ?     //       if X is not equal to 0:
        Y ?   //         if Y is not equal to 0:
          b   //           return the original union
        :     //         else (Y = 0 / y = 'never'):
          x   //           return x
      :       //       else (X = 0 / x = 'never'):
        y     //         return y
    :         //     else (intersection):
      N       //       return 'never'
```

Answer (score 4):

## C++ TMP, <s>476</s> 466 bytes

I'm surprised I got this far with it. `U` is union, `I` is intersection, `R` is the solution function that defines the solution type `t`. [Online version with tests.](https://godbolt.org/z/KcK4nfKs4)

```
#define Z template
#define C class
#define K Z<C A>C R
#define T(x){public:using t=x;};
C string;C number;C boolean;C undefined;C null;C any;C never;using X=any;using Y=never;Z<C...>C U;Z<C...>C I;K T(A)K<U<A,A>>T(A)K<I<A,A>>T(A)Z<C A,C B>C R<I<A,B>>T(Y)K<U<A,X>>T(X)K<U<X,A>>T(X)K<I<X,A>>T(X)K<I<A,X>>T(X)Z<>C R<I<Y,X>>T(Y)Z<>C R<I<X,Y>>T(Y)K<U<A,Y>>T(A)K<U<Y,A>>T(A)Z<>C R<U<Y,X>>T(X)Z<>C R<U<X,Y>>T(X)Z<>C R<U<Y,Y>>T(Y)K<I<Y,A>>T(Y)K<I<A,Y>>T(Y)Z<>C R<I<Y,Y>>T(Y)
```

I'm certain this could be compacted further, maybe even to around 350 bytes. If anyone wants to give it a try, here is the version without preprocessor directives:

```
struct string;
struct number;
struct boolean;
struct undefined;
struct null;
struct any;
struct never;
using X=any;
using Y=never;
template<class A>struct T{using t=A;};
template<class...>struct U;
template<class...>struct I;
template<class A>struct R:T<A>{};
template<class A>struct R<U<A,A>>:T<A>{};
template<class A>struct R<I<A,A>>:T<A>{};
template<class A,class B>struct R<I<A,B>>:T<Y>{};
template<class A>struct R<U<A,X>>:T<X>{};
template<class A>struct R<U<X,A>>:T<X>{};
template<class A>struct R<I<X,A>>:T<X>{};
template<class A>struct R<I<A,X>>:T<X>{};
template<>struct R<I<Y,X>>:T<Y>{};
template<>struct R<I<X,Y>>:T<Y>{};
template<class A>struct R<U<A,Y>>:T<A>{};
template<class A>struct R<U<Y,A>>:T<A>{};
template<>struct R<U<Y,X>>:T<X>{};
template<>struct R<U<X,Y>>:T<X>{};
template<>struct R<U<Y,Y>>:T<Y>{};
template<class A>struct R<I<Y,A>>:T<Y>{};
template<class A>struct R<I<A,Y>>:T<Y>{};
template<>struct R<I<Y,Y>>:T<Y>{};
```

Comment: Holy moly, C++ templates was _not_ a solution I expected to see for this, but I'm very glad I did. Nice work, very impressive.

Comment: This is nightmare fuel.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 261 bytes

```python
lambda x,o="&",y="":("any"in x+y)*(o<"|")*-~-("never"in x+y)*"any"or(lambda r:r==31and"any"or"|".join("ubsnnnotuudormleliblfene iagr nn   e    d"[i::5]for i in range(5)if r&2**i)or"never")(eval(o.join(str(min(31,2**"dormlyv".find(k[2])%64))for k in[x,y or x])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDNjpswED7DU4wsFdksQcqm2wNa@iI0B6eY1F0YIxuiIEV99XTAQMjuATP@5vsZTzt0fwwe7lX@617L5lRKuCYmZxFLhpyxjDOJA9MI15dBxNy8sxsT8e7fjjNUF2XX1sQzls8mNrN5fthLLOcG6dK/RiNn/ckhoun6vjS2qVWtT3WlUIGWZwuIAKDog5IVOsvejpWxoIFyrMSz4m9CV2Cj1zjWgmz9FIKri6y58RGus7yh/2GfEI1NMcOFpZXGkn8Ur0fx7cd3IUbjDzIurskAVF@PQoi7blpjO3CDC8ORUetxNByB1HWlxtQqWXKRurbW3dh1XGRhICGfuB7nIgyscoRVPJZFttsfBQnbWv5WnAFLgDGiSOcUhU3MHGRBtDBorcZuURFx95PoRBF3epjGcxAEvgixb07K0t0XIa2aLnSG01rGxvgPPR1usAg8cJtla7vHUtGSVBms1W2OWjnLDM94tFo/JUYby0@NTz409MZ8fIJH5ocsQPSF8kjeIF7kE6fz6@ALPO1sXdkjcSt@pD6jk/YZ2qr/Aw)

-1 byet thanks to ovs

Comment: `(1-("never"in x+y))` can be shortened to `-~-("never"in x+y)` or `0**("never"in x+y)`.

Comment: @ovs `0**` is very clever. also i did not realize using complement would actually make it short enough; should've tried more combinations

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 120 bytes

```
never \| (\w+)|(\w+) (\| never|[|&] \1)
$1$2
any & never|never & any
never
any [|&] \w+|\w+ [|&] any
any
\w+ & \w+
never
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVNLTsMwEN3nFLOoIqouqnIDlhyAFWXhJlNqyZlG9qQhktccgCNykeBf82kDLGzZ7734vbEnGlmS6HvCC2rYW3jYt5u1DbNbWwiEfbX5G@x362y1Wz1mgjrIExM/zMFhWVgHNurbjXUjbjzvhwdyT0V132@38KQUHISRhVOVUCEL4K5GA0ZWteqgEjXwGfiElUF1QZMZ1pLe4fvzC@Iyo6Y6uCAeicuQw2@HZJEMGTPn@kLyTAYOyC0ipQDRt9AoGKGJCvwosGZoJZ8WMliYWN9go6ahEo@SsJzLBnhU3pfmwz4TozZY8H@ZY6V/R86nkeOFDMw86A25nC1dZDDzl56SpBeflzSC45N47L7G4TiNplEMksJuWtnYb/mSx6zMCfh7L4ynQidRlf7u4OwmDSehjqmNlt7oytw3nV00XKg1yjRyoykprz/XxG9OXO3m6I3hDw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
never \| (\w+)|(\w+) (\| never|[|&] \1)
$1$2
```

Simplify unions with `never` and self-unions and intersections.

```
any & never|never & any
never
```

Simplify intersections between `any` and `never`.

```
any [|&] \w+|\w+ [|&] any
any
```

Simplify any other intersections of `any`.

```
\w+ & \w+
never
```

Simplify any other intersections.